# How to access google drive spreadsheet from different account in android?

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to access google drive spreadsheet for login user.I made a demo for it but its only for only one account using google drive API.Can I use google drive API for login user?if yes,then how to do it?..please help me...Thanks in advance

public void Create_Spreadsheet() {

```
    DocsService docsService = new DocsService("MySampleApplication-v3");
    try {
        docsService.setUserCredentials("email",
                "password");
        URL GOOGLE_DRIVE_FEED_URL = new URL(
                "https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/");
        DocumentListEntry documentListEntry = new com.google.gdata.data.docs.SpreadsheetEntry();
        documentListEntry.setTitle(new PlainTextConstruct(
                et_en.getText().toString()));
        documentListEntry = docsService.insert(GOOGLE_DRIVE_FEED_URL,
                documentListEntry);


    } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ServiceException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}

```
As shown above..I made a demo for create spreadsheet .but its only for my account.

And in AndroidManifest.....

<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.apps.drive.APP_ID"
            android:value="API-KEY" />
```

Comment: I think you are looking for OAuth2 - it lets people issue a "key" that lets you login to their accounts, without a password. This is a good tutorial: http://masashi-k.blogspot.com.au/2013/06/sending-mail-with-gmail-using-xoauth2.html  Maybe there is a good tutorial for drive api + OAuth Playground.

Comment: yes..but key is used only for one account.I am looking for all users accounts

Comment: In which users can login and add data in own spreadsheets.

Comment: What is the demo you made? Do you mean share a spreadsheet with another account? Can you describe with an example, describe the steps with expected outcome.

Comment: Still think you are looking for OAuth2. It lets any google docs user use your app. It does so without your app ever knowing their password.  .... Can you describe with an example, describe the steps with expected outcome.

Comment: OK...Firstly..in my App, I want to do that..user can login and logout...if user is login than user can create spreadsheet and add data on created spreadsheet.after that user can logout it.

Comment: That is what OAuth2 is for. Good luck with it.